# Plotting a heatmap over an image on seaborn

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, seaborn, heatmap

Im using seaborn to plot an heatmap over an image, the data is a matrix 41x41 on a excel file and the image is 890px by 890px, each value in the matrix contains a  value for pollutant concentration, and the image is a map from google earth, but im getting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUKhA.jpg). The image is too big for the graph and I dont know how to fit the two together because the plot is always 41px by 41px, how can i do this?
here is the code:

````
import scipy.misc as sci
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

excel_file = "2002marçoSO2vFINAL1.xls"
xldata = pd.read_excel(excel_file,
                       sheet_name = "Python")
heatmap_data = xldata
sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap="gist_stern", alpha = 0.2)
img = sci.imread("50x50.png")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()```
````

Comment: Maybe using `plt.imshow(heatmap_data, extent=[0, 889, 0, 889], cmap="gist_stern", alpha = 0.2)` helps?

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.